# Django-storages + django-pipeline + gzip

Tags: django, django-pipeline, python-django-storages

I would like to gzip my static assets to s3 with the Gzip and s3 mixins from django storages, and serve the gzipped files with the static/compressed template tag.  Is this possible?  I don't see information in the docs or online on serving compressed versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  See the docs on Gzip compression and the following section.

https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storages.html#gzip-compression

Also see this question:
[django-pipeline with s3 storage is not compressing my js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679243/django-pipeline-with-s3-storage-is-not-compressing-my-js)